# HTML specific slideshow

Tags: html, slideshow

This is my progress of my browser racing game. As you can see the car is rotatable by clicking the buttons below the car. But what I am trying to do is to remove those buttons and do the following: I hold my left mouse button on the car, and I move my mouse to some direction (left or right).

If its left, the the slideshow gets me to my previous photo, if it is right the slideshow moves 1 picture forward. If I have to say it with one word, I want to rotate my car like in need for speed. I know that this code is easy one but I can't find help anywhere in Google or this site.

[image]

Here is also the code of my car slideshow.

```html
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">

        <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
    <img src="../styles/test/12.png" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-display-middle w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
      <h3 style="text-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #87F, 0 0 0.2em #87F,
        0 0 0.2em #87F; color: aqua;">ROTATE</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
    <img src="../styles/test/1.png" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-display-middle w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
    <h3 style="text-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #87F, 0 0 0.2em #87F,
        0 0 0.2em #87F; color: aqua;">ROTATE</h3>
  </div>
</div>
        <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
    <img src="../styles/test/2.png" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-display-middle w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
      <h3 style="text-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #87F, 0 0 0.2em #87F,
        0 0 0.2em #87F; color: aqua;">ROTATE</h3>
  </div>
</div>
        <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
    <img src="../styles/test/3.png" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-display-middle w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
      <h3 style="text-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #87F, 0 0 0.2em #87F,
        0 0 0.2em #87F; color: aqua;">ROTATE</h3>
  </div>
</div>
        <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
    <img src="../styles/test/4.png" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-display-middle w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
      <h3 style="text-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #87F, 0 0 0.2em #87F,
        0 0 0.2em #87F; color: aqua;">ROTATE</h3>
  </div>
</div>
        <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
    <img src="../styles/test/5.png" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-display-middle w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
      <h3 style="text-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #87F, 0 0 0.2em #87F,
        0 0 0.2em #87F; color: aqua;">ROTATE</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
    <img src="../styles/test/6.png" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-display-middle w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
      <h3 style="text-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #87F, 0 0 0.2em #87F,
        0 0 0.2em #87F; color: aqua;">ROTATE</h3>
  </div>
</div>
        <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
    <img src="../styles/test/7.png" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-display-middle w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
      <h3 style="text-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #87F, 0 0 0.2em #87F,
        0 0 0.2em #87F; color: aqua;">ROTATE</h3>
  </div>
</div>
        <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
    <img src="../styles/test/8.png" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-display-middle w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
      <h3 style="text-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #87F, 0 0 0.2em #87F,
        0 0 0.2em #87F; color: aqua;">ROTATE</h3>
  </div>
</div>
        <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
    <img src="../styles/test/9.png" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-display-middle w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
      <h3 style="text-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #87F, 0 0 0.2em #87F,
        0 0 0.2em #87F; color: aqua;">ROTATE</h3>
  </div>
</div>
        <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
    <img src="../styles/test/10.png" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-display-middle w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
      <h3 style="text-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #87F, 0 0 0.2em #87F,
        0 0 0.2em #87F; color: aqua;">ROTATE</h3>
  </div>
</div>
        <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
    <img src="../styles/test/11.png" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-display-middle w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
      <h3 style="text-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #87F, 0 0 0.2em #87F,
        0 0 0.2em #87F; color: aqua;">ROTATE</h3>
  </div>
</div>
        

<button class="w3-button w3-display-right w3-black" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10094;</button>
<button class="w3-button w3-display-left w3-black" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10095;</button>

</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? As im pretty sure this will involve javascript you could essentially use threejs i think.

Comment: Well bro, look at my car picture over there, that is simply a div made for slideshow, made out of 12 png images(my car images). Each image has the same car on it but on a different angle. Seems that this threejs stuff that you mentioned is licensed. I don't wana get myself into any licenses and stuff like that. Which is why i also wont use car brands from real life. I was hoping that someone will give me the code i am looking for. And btw, i don't want 3d model into my website, i want just to change the controls of the slideshow... that's all.

Comment: The question is pretty broad. Find an open source library for detecting drag events and apply the function call from your click handlers.

Comment: Hey i think this will guide you https://css-tricks.com/simple-swipe-with-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for!! Thanks A. Meshu!!!! <3 If you are still here i will ask you how to mark your answer as useful?